# What is this brown deposit at the bottom of my Oil can?

Tags: oil

We use Filtered groundnut oil for cooking at home. However, we recently changed the brand due to non-availability during COVID-19 lock-down. While pouring the last bit of oil I saw this at the bottom. The brown coloration was stuck to the walls of the can and some of it was floating in the leftover oil (not clearly visible here). It looked flaky.

Was the oil impure/adulterated/unhealthy? Or is this normal for filtered groundnut oil?

[image: Photo of the inside of the can]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is just fine material from the grinding process that got through the filters and settled over time. It's pretty normal, it just means this company's filtering process isn't as effective as your previous brand. There shouldn't be any food safety considerations with that, my only consideration would be that suspended fine particles will lower the burn temperature of the oil some. There doesn't seem to be that much in there, if you are having no problems using the oil then you look good to go.

Comment: Would there not be a food safety concern for anyone with a peanut allergy? Highly refined peanut oils are apparently safe for people with allergies only because the proteins have been filtered out.

Comment: I don't know anyone with a peanut allergy who would touch peanut oil no matter how refined @bdsl!